# In Typescript, why do I need to declare a property outside the class' constructor, unlike Javascript where I wouldn't need to do so?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

In Javascript I could create a class like below, meaning I wouldn't need to declare and initiate a property called `logs` outside of the constructor:

```
class Logger {
  constructor() {
    this.logs = [];
  }
}
```

However, in typescript it would give me an error:
`Property 'logs' does not exist on type 'Logger'.ts(2339)`
To fix it I declared a property *logs* like this: `logs: Array<any>;`
Pseudo code in Typescript without errors looks like:

```
class Logger {
  logs: Array<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.logs = [];
  }
}
```

This is likely a Typescript beginners question. However, I've looked into the docs and other resources and couldn't find an explanation.
Since I know how to fix, I'm more interested in the explanation, differences and best practices.

Comment: TS is about *type safety*. If you try to assign to a property that TS thinks shouldn't exist, then it will stop you. Because it seems like a bug. And there is nothing at all in your code that indicates that `logs` is a valid property in your class. Hence, TS deduces it shouldn't exist.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but I don't know how to get a canonical answer for it.  [microsoft/TypeScript#37920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/37920) (released with TS4.0) implemented something similar for checking of JS files, but you still need to *declare* class properties in TS files.  If there is an authoritative answer, it would be some documented decision by the TS team for why the compiler doesn't infer the existence of a property from its usage; it's easy to speculate that it would fail to catch too many real errors, but I don't know if that's really the issue.

Comment: Ahh, here it is [microsoft/TypeScript#766](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/766), with [this comment in particular](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/766#issuecomment-58293623) for why it is the way it is. Maybe I'll flesh that out into an answer when I get the chance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "why" is tricky. There are two parts to this question

**1. Why is a type definition needed?**

VLAZ has already covered in their comment. TypeScript doesn't have enough to infer the type so it needs more explicit guidance.

"Surely TS can figure out that its an array!", that is true, however...

**2. Why is the type definition needed at the top?**

The constructor in this case confuses things, but lets take a slightly different class:

```
class Logger { 
  a() {
    this.logs = 1234;
  }

  b() {
    this.logs = ['a', 'b']
  }
}
```

From the above, what type is `logs`? It depends right? If `a()` is called first, then its a number, otherwise its an array. "depends" isn't really good enough to give us strong confidence in our types. So (I think) Typescript is forcing you to declare it in one central spot - the top of the class, outside of any method.

You might also ask why can't it infer from the constructor? That would always come before `a()` or `b()`.

I suspect its related to the fact that fields can be set during their declaration, like:

```
class Logger {
  logs: Array<string> = ['a', 'b'];
  
  constructor() {
    this.logs = 6611; // <-- wait a second...
  }
}
```